# Rails open-uri resque all errors and remove from array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My code:

```
  feeds = Website.find(:all).map{|w| w.feed_url}

  feeds.each do |u|
    begin 
      open(u)
    rescue
      feeds.delete(u)
    end
  end
```

Example feeds could be: `['http://da.wordpress.org/feed/', 'asdasd']`

I want to rescue any error and remove the feed url from the feed array if any error.. In this case asdasd should be removed.

Terminal:

```
irb(main):133:0> feeds =  ['http://da.wordpress.org/feed/', 'asdasd']
=> ["http://da.wordpress.org/feed/", "asdasd"]
irb(main):134:0>  feeds.each do |u|
irb(main):135:1*     begin
irb(main):136:2*       open(u)
irb(main):137:2>     rescue
irb(main):138:2>       feeds.delete(u)
irb(main):139:2>     end
irb(main):140:1>   end
=> ["asdasd"]
```

It just removes the first element in the array instead of removing asdasd...

Comment: didn't get your point. Anything wrong with your code?

Comment: it is not working as expected I would expect it to remove asdasd as it would give a ERRNONET error instead it just removes the first element in the feed array.

Comment: I just tried your code and am getting `["http://da.wordpress.org/feed/"]` returned. Are you sure you don't have any typos or spacing errors? From the looks of your code, it looks like you may have some issues with your `begin` declaration in terminal.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you've gone and started IRB instead of the rails console or that you need to `require 'open-uri'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the code as below, and it works fine :

```
require 'open-uri'
feeds =  ['http://da.wordpress.org/feed/', 'asdasd']  
feeds.dup.each do|u| 
  begin 
    open(u) 
  rescue Errno::ENOENT
    feeds.delete(u) 
  end
end
p feeds 
# >> ["http://da.wordpress.org/feed/"]
```

Although your version is working,but it is not good practice.

```
require 'open-uri'
feeds =  ['http://da.wordpress.org/feed/', 'asdasd']  
feeds.each do|u| 
  begin 
    open(u) 
  rescue 
    feeds.delete(u) 
  end
end
p feeds 
# >> ["http://da.wordpress.org/feed/"]
```